# Modal Pop Up validation AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, bootstrap-modal

I have my code and it validates the format of the entered input on button click but when I enter a value that is in the correct format, the modal still shows. What I want is that when the input is in the correct format no modal pop up will be shown. Here is my plunker link : http://plnkr.co/edit/gCQ4tKNkd0LVZ57mSw4W?p=preview

The jscodes is as shown :

```
 $scope.upd_check = function(value)
{
    var patt = new RegExp("/^\d{5}$/");
    var res = patt.test(value);

    if(!res)
    {
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    }

}
```

I'm using angularJS. Any Help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...
1) you expect "value" but you don't provide anything.
2) you regex is wrong.
3) you need to check the regex against "$scope.MyModel.text" or alternatively ng-model="text" and then evaluate "$scope.text".
4) don't check manually "regex.test", this is why you use ng-pattern for. Check the docs for the use of form validation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: Thanks @KobiCohen Im new in angularjs and if its not too much of your time can you give me a sample?

Comment: Thanks @KobeCohen but why is it that it is okay when I entered 1, theres no modal but when I entered 2, 9 and 10 the modal is still shown?

Comment: This is due to an error in my regex, i've mistakenly put /g at the end. just remove it

Comment: Thanks @KobiCohen, I have one last question. What If I want to expand the range from 0 to 65535?

Comment: /(6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]\d|65[0-4](\d){2}|6[0-4](\d){3}|[1-5](\d){4}|[1-9](\d){0,3})/ taken from http://regexlib.com/

Comment: By the way, if this answer helped you, you're welcome to accept :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103042/discussion-between-bleykfaust-and-kobi-cohen).